# Wordpress contact form 7 hidden date field not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, datefield

I am using contact form 7,Contact Form 7 Modules plugins on wordpress4.5.2.
My need is i want to capture post_date (the date on which post has been published) and submission_date(the date on which a candidate submit form.

i am trying to achieve above two needs using following tags which is always returning me 'null'/empty in generated email..some pointers are appreciated.

```
CF7 form
[hidden today_date today]

[hidden post_date id:post_date]

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>

on mail , below tags used..
1 [_post_date]
2 [post_date] 
[_format_post_date "D, d M y"]
3 [today_date]
[_format_today_date "D, d M y"]
4 [_today_date]

result email..
1 [_post_date]
2 

3

4 [_today_date]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CF7 form tags

[hidden post_date "post_date"]

[date today_date _date]  // this is not required

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>

Mail tags should be..
[_format_post_date "Y-m-d"]
[_date] --> to get current date
```